# How to change the content on a switch using before and after classes?

Tags: html, css

I need to place a content on a slider switch by using css but Iam unable to get the after class for a content.

Below is my html and css code:

```css
 .slider {
   position: absolute;
   cursor: pointer;
   top:0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: #ccc;
   -webkit-transition: .4s;
   transition: .4s;
}
.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "Y";
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: center;
    font-size:14px;
    color:white;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:-6px;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}
.slider:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "N";
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: center;
    font-size:14px;
    color:white;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:-6px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
   background-color:#6ab8f7;
}
   input:focus + .slider {
   box-shadow: 0 0 1px #6ab8f7;
}
   input:checked + .slider:before {
   -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
   -ms-transform: translateX(20px);
   transform: translateX(20px);
}
.slider.round {
   border-radius: 34px;
}
.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox">
<div class="slider round"></div>
```

This was the output I got.

[image]

But I need to change the content to "N" and color of the slider to "white". But in my case I am getting the following output by using after class.

[image]

I need to change the color and content when it is toggled.

Comment: Please also show your after class.

Comment: @Super Cool Handsome Gel Boy  Yes I updated with after class

Comment: can u post full code. I mean with the switch class

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle so everyone will understand your code. Else you can add snippet here itself. try.

Comment: @Jaffer Wilson Yes I updated with css code.Can you check it once please.

Comment: try running the code snippet. see how bad it looks like. is that what you want with full page background and switch in one corner thats not even visible? get some exact code friend (like full page code with its parents and its classes)

Comment: @swathi Thank you for your update. Can you share a link of site where you have found such a content change after toggling.... I will be happy to solve your query, if you provide a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Add the next sibling to tag (`~`) with the checking of `:checked` to achieve this

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .slider:before {
position: absolute;
content: "Y";
font-weight: bold;
vertical-align: center;
font-size:14px;
color:white;
height: 26px;
width: 26px;
left: 0px;
right:0px;
bottom:-6px;
background-color: #2196F3;
-webkit-transition: .4s;
transition: .4s;
}
input[type=checkbox] ~ .slider:before {
position: absolute;
content: "N";
font-weight: bold;
vertical-align: center;
font-size:14px;
color:white;
height: 26px;
width: 26px;
left: 0px;
right:0px;
bottom:-6px;
background-color: white;
-webkit-transition: .4s;
transition: .4s;
}
```

Comment: No it is not working for me.Please can you check the updated css code.